# In the plane, if every boundary of a unit circle center at a blue point contain exactly 10 red points can there be more blue points than red points?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

There are finitely many points in the plane which is colored red and blue  , for every blue point $x$ we always have |{$y: |x-y| = 1, y$ is red}| = 10. Can there be more blue points than red points?

I have struggled this problem for quite a while but only figure out:

1: Let $A_c$ be the red points lie on the circle $(c, 1)$ then $|A_i \cap A_j| \le 2$ and  $|A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k| \le 1$ for every blue points $i, j, k$ but it does not solve the problem because there are configuration such that $|A_i| = 10, |A_i\cap A_j| \le 1$ and there are more sets than elements. We need more geometric properties from circles to solve in this way

2: if we change from "exactly 10" to "at least 10" then the answer is YES. the configuration is blue points are {$(x/M, y/M): 1\le x,y \le N, x+y$ is odd} and red points are {$(x/M, y/M): 1\le x,y \le N, x+y$ is even} for some large odd integer $N$ and an appropriated integer $M$

Comment: So just to be clear, you want the unit *disk* at each blue point to contain 10 red points? I.e. the red points don’t have to lie on the circle itself - just within it.

Comment: Is it even possible to satisfy the hypothesis in the first place? As we vary the circle's center continuously, the number of red points in the disk is a semi-continuous function (which way depends on whether we're taking closed or open disks) and it seems impossible to arrange it so that there aren't any jump discontinuities.

Comment: As English is not my native language, i am very sorry for the confusion, i meant the set $\{y: |x-y| = 1\}$ not the set $\{y: |x-y| \le 1\}$